# How to use paypal payflow api to charge sale in canadian dollars

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I have a custom application that is integrated with the paypal payflow API.  We are expanding to Canada and would like to charge in the Canadian dollar for our Canadian customers but it keeps defaulting to the US Dollar.

I'm trying to pass 'CURRENCY'=> 'CAD' in the REST call via curl.  I can't find any documentation other than the currency code is CAD.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using payflow api or rest api? If you're using payflow api and you have a paypal manager account, maybe it's because your processor doesn't support transaction currency, see this: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#paypal-credit-card-transaction-request-parameters . You can find your processor information in your PayPal manager account->Account Administration.